# .net c# excel column AutoFit without shrinking

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

My problem is I want to resize columns to the maximum of their current size and the size dictated by AutoFit (purely for cosmetic reasons - eg some columns only have one digit and should not shrink that small etc).

Currently solution is:

```
foreach (Excel.Range column in dataRows.Columns)
{
    double oldWidth = column.ColumnWidth;
    column.AutoFit();
    double newWidth = column.ColumnWidth;
    column.ColumnWidth = Math.Max(oldWidth, newWidth);
}
```

Surely there must be some inbuilt method that I am missing to do this? I would've thought AutoFit() would have overloading options but it did not.

Comment: you are right there is no overload for the AutoFit. My suggestion is to check when the minimum length is below your (const) minimum length, once it falls below then increase it by your const minimum length - current minimum length. You can implement this by overrideing autofit i think

Comment: I think what you're doing is about as good as it gets. You could get rid of the NewWidth variable and put the  whole thing in a function. That wouldn't be too bad, would it?